# Virtualbox guest won't run - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I've attempted to find an answer, but can't find one.

I've installed Virtualbox 5.0.18 from apt.

It installs and runs, but as soon as I try to start a guest, I get errors, and the guest won't run.

Uninstalling virtualbox and installing virtualbox-dkms first fails.
I've installed the libelf-dev package as this was mentioned in an earlier dkms make.log.

The make.log is as follows:

> DKMS make.log for virtualbox-5.0.18 for kernel 4.15.0-33-generic
>   (x86_64) do 30 aug 2018 16:42:20 CEST make: Map
>   '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic' wordt binnengegaan   CC [M]
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
>   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o   CC
>   [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.o   CC
>   [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o   CC
>   [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o: warning:
>   objtool: .text+0x7: indirect jump found in RETPOLINE build   CC [M] 
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/SUPLibAll.o   CC [M] 
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o   CC
>   [M] 
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o
>   In file included from
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:31:0:
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:
>   In function ‘VBoxHost_RTMemContAlloc’:
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:309:47:
>   error: implicit declaration of function ‘set_pages_x’
>   [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]  # define
>   MY_SET_PAGES_EXEC(pPages, cPages)    set_pages_x(pPages, cPages)
>                                                  ^ /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:444:13:
>   note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_SET_PAGES_EXEC’
>                MY_SET_PAGES_EXEC(&paPages[iPage], 1);
>                ^ /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:
>   In function ‘VBoxHost_RTMemContFree’:
>   /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:310:47:
>   error: implicit declaration of function ‘set_pages_nx’
>   [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]  # define
>   MY_SET_PAGES_NOEXEC(pPages, cPages)  set_pages_nx(pPages, cPages)
>                                                  ^ /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c:492:13:
>   note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_SET_PAGES_NOEXEC’
>                MY_SET_PAGES_NOEXEC(&paPages[iPage], 1);
>                ^ cc1: some warnings being treated as errors scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target
>   '/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o'
>   failed make[2]: ***
>   [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o]
>   Error 1 scripts/Makefile.build:606: recipe for target
>   '/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv' failed make[1]: ***
>   [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.18/build/vboxdrv] Error 2

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to have your -updates repository enabled. The current version of vbox in 16.04 is 5.0.38.

Comment: I didn't. Thank you.
I did resolve it by going to the virtualbox website though... 
One lives and learns

Answer (score 0):

Well...
I fixed it by going outside of Ubuntu and install a newer version of VirtualBox.

@user535733 pointed out I may not have "updates" turned on... I didn't.

Thanks for the suggestions!